# Probability Density Function of Gamma Distribution

Tags: statistics

$$f_{T_r}(t)=\lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow0}\frac{P(t\le T_r\le t+\Delta t)}{\Delta t}$$

I get $\lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow0}P(t\le T_r\le t+\Delta t)$ because the purpose of this probability desity function is to find the probability near $t$, but why divide by $\Delta$t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if we didn't divide by $\Delta t$ the we would get $0$ for the density: $$
\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}P(t\le T_r\le t+\Delta t)=0.$$

Second: By the definition of the density, if it exists then $$ P(t\le T_r\le t+\Delta t)=\int_t^{t+\Delta t}f_{T_r}(u)\ du\approx\Delta tf_{T_r}(t).$$

Dividing both sides by $\Delta t$ we get that $$ \frac{P(t\le T_r\le t+\Delta t)}{\Delta t}\approx f_{T_r}(t).$$

That is, if the limit in question exists for all $t$ then it has to equal the density.

Comment: Interesting! Can I use the equation in the question to derive the probability density function of all continuous distributions, not just Gamma? So in a sense, it's a general p.d.f. ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.